# Python: Monte Carlo Rabin-Karp search

Tags: python, search

I am trying to implement a Monte Carlo Rabin-Karp search in Python.
This is what I have so far (random_prime is a function that returns a prime number less than the limit arguement given):

```
def search(pattern, text):

m = len(pattern)
n = len(text)
q = random_prime(m*n*n)
r = (2^(m - 1)) % q
f = []
for x in range (0, n + 1):
    f.append(0)

pFinger = 0
for j in range(0, m):
    f[0] = (2 * f[0]) + (int(text[j]) % q)
    pFinger = (2 * pFinger) + (int(pattern[j]) % q)

i = 0
while (i + m) < n:
    if (f[i] == pFinger):
        print "Match at position " + str(i)
    f[i + 1] = (2 * (f[i] - (r * int(text[i])))) + (int(text[i + m]) % q)
    i += 1
```

The only problem is, it seems to only match the first character or characters.

e.g. if I call search('01', '101110001010101'), I get no match.

Or if I call search('1', '111110110100101') I get a match.

Or if I call search('0', '0000001110001010101') I get matches up to position 5.

Is there something wrong with the code that is causing it to match incorrectly?

Comment: It's possible to debug this for you, but it won't help you much.

Try adding printouts to your code. At each iteration, for example, print out what is the fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no genius but I think I found the root of your issue. In the line 
r = (2^(m - 1)) % q , it is to my knowledge that the ^ is not the correct character for creating an exponential function. The correct character to use in python would be ** such that r = (2**(m - 1)) % q. Your search should now print all positions except the last. This can then be fixed by changing < n to <= n in the line (while (i+m)< n:)

You code will now print all positions although you will receive an index error which only occurs once all positions have been identified. This can be solved by ignoring this error once it occurs.

try:

```
   f[i + 1] = (2 * (f[i] - (r * int(text[i])))) + (int(text[i + m]) % q)

   i += 1
```

except:

```
   break
```